# How do I find the last row in a column I'm currently looping through

Tags: vba, excel

`c` specifies the columns I'm looping through and the Style is a highlight applied to blank cells. If the cell is blank I need the ID of that row `(Cells(i,4))` to be copied to a reports page in the column `c` that I'm currently looping through. For readability I'm trying to copy each instance in the next available cell of that row but as you can imagine I'm getting an error at the `Range(c & Rows.Count)` portion of the code.

I'm aware that I can put `A` or any other column letter there but i'm just wondering if i were to be able to put the variable that I'm iterating with there instead. Any tips for this?

```
For c = 1 To 103
    For i = 1 To coor(2)
        If Cells(i, c).Style = "60% - Accent2" Then
            Cells(i, 4).Copy Sheets("ReportsPage").Range(c & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next i
Next c
```

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Answer (score 2):

Use `Cells()` instead of `Range()`.  `Cells()` allows for the use of cardinal location:

```
For c = 1 To 103
    For i = 1 To coor(2)
        If Cells(i, c).Style = "60% - Accent2" Then
            Cells(i, 4).Copy Sheets("ReportsPage").Cells(Rows.Count,c).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next i
Next c
```

One more note, one should always append any range object with their parent sheet, even if it is the activesheet:

```
With ActiveSheet
    For c = 1 To 103
        For i = 1 To coor(2)
            If .Cells(i, c).Style = "60% - Accent2" Then
                .Cells(i, 4).Copy Sheets("ReportsPage").Cells(Rows.Count,c).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next i
    Next c
End With
```

Comment: Sorry that this is off-topic but I find it funny that rep rounds up. I was going to say gratz on 80k but your profile says it's still 79.9k

Comment: I'm switching in between a few sheets and am specifying which ones I'm running operations on. Good tip though

Comment: @Officer_Narc then you could change `ActiveSheet` to `Sheets(i)` if you're looping on `Sheets.count` or the variable name you're using if it's an object loop (`ws` in `For each ws in Workbook.Sheets`)

Comment: Gratz Scott! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to find the last column:

```
Dim LastCol As Integer
With ActiveSheet
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```